# fopen php positional file line

Tags: php, fopen

I have a problem reading a .ret or .txt file while using the function below it deletes line space from the file. Except that this file is positional I will do a routine to search for information based on your positioning.

```
$ponteiro = fopen('arquivoretorno\retorno.ret','rb');
//$vetor = array();                       
while (!feof($ponteiro)) {

        $linha = fgets($ponteiro,9999);

        $tipo_registro = substr($linha, 7, 1);
        echo $linha;
        //echo $tipo_registro;
        die();
        IF ($tipo_registro == 0) {
          $codbanco = substr($linha, 1, 3); //Código do Banco na Compensação: "085"
          $lote = substr($linha, 4, 4); //Lote de Serviço: "0000"          
          $inpessoa = substr($linha, 18, 1); //Tipo de Inscrição da Empresa
          $nmcnpjcpf = substr($linha, 19, 14); //Número de Inscrição da Empresa
          $nmconvenio = substr($linha, 33, 20); //Código do Convênio na Cooperativa
          $agencia = substr($linha, 53, 5); //Agência da sede da Cooperativa
          $div_agencia = substr($linha, 58, 1); //Dígito Verificador da Agência
          $numcontacorrente = substr($linha, 59, 12); //Número da Conta Corrente
          $dv_contacorrente = substr($linha, 71, 1); //Dígito Verificador da Conta    
          $codremessa = substr($linha, 143, 1); //Código Remessa / Retorno        
          } ElseIf ($tipo_registro == 3) {
             $segmento = substr($linha, 14, 1);    //Cód. Segmento do Registro Detalhe           

             If ($segmento == 'T') {
              $vlnumbol = substr($linha, 38, 20);  //Identificação do Título 
              $inpessoacliente = substr($linha, 133, 1);   //Tipo de Inscrição
              $nmcnpjcpfcliente = substr($linha, 134, 15); //Número de Inscrição
              $vltitoriginal = number_format(substr($linha, 82, 15),2,',','.') ; //Valor do Título
             } ElseIf ($tipo_registro == 'U' ) {

            }
          }



}
fclose ($ponteiro);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HwF0.jpg)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `<pre>` tag for printing the data. Something like this:

```
 echo "<pre>";
 echo $linha;
 echo "</pre>";
```

OR

```
$linha = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $linha);
echo $linda;
```

Comment: Most would like to use inside a property in php not just display the screen echo. Any idea?

Comment: @user3303036 Try this: $linha = str_replace(' ', '&nbsp;', $linha);